# How to make a mask image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using MATLAB's roipoly to create a mask.

The problem is that I have so many points for row and column arguments to roipoly. when I use it with fewer points, I mean at the order of multiple tens, it works correctly, but as I give row and column arguments with larger vectors, in order of hundreds, it omits some and give me a mask made by some part of the vectors! Does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
function OutputImage = FillSelectedRegion(InputImage,Row,Col)

  OutputImage = InputImage;
  OutputImage(:,:) = 0;
  OutputImage = uint8(roipoly(OutputImage,Col,Row));
```

If anyone knows how to fix it or using another method, please guide me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to look at 'Col' and 'Row' for both success and failure cases?

Comment: can you post more info on the sizes of the vectors/images in question when they cause trouble versus when they don't?

Comment: also, check that the entries in the row/column are unique, that is, assuming Row/Column are column arrays, compare length(Row) to size(unique([row column],'rows'),1)

Comment: Frederick, those are two vectors at the same size like this: Row = [245; 247; 264; ...] and Col = [204; 217; 275; ...]

Comment: Size of image in both conditions is 480x640 which is double and row and column about 500x1 which are double too.

Comment: I'm completely sure that Col and Row are the same size.